# Usage of "weakly" when dealing with properties in the weak topology

Tags: terminology, weak-topology

Sometimes, when I read about topologies, for example the weak topology, they usually say "converges weakly", or "weakly continuous", "weakly open", etc., something similar, without mentioning what they mean by using "weakly" in this context.

Is the term "weakly" added beside a property with it is associated with the weak topology, or how exactly? Do people say, "--- is **something** weakly" if "--- is **something** with respect to the weak topology"? (Note, they first talk about the weakly topology, thereafter they say something "weakly", not the converse direction.)

The same goes for other kind of topologies.

Comment: Converges *weakly* means converges wrt the weak topology. Same applies to weak continuity.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier I think I get it. But, is there a way to define short instead of saying what we mean by "converges weakly, weakly continuous, weakly etc etc etc" so much more, when we are doing with the weak topology? Can I simply say, "we say that something is weakly if it is associated with the weak topology"?

Comment: Yes, you can (at least in this context). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology.

Answer (score 1):

If the property relates to a topic in analysis (e.g. convergence, continuity, compactness, etc.) then most of the time "Weakly X" refers to "X under the weak topology". Thematically, this means "watch out if your space is infinite-dimensional" because the weak and strong topologies do not necessarily coincide in that context.

In response to a comment above: while it is very common to use "weakly" in this format, I've never seen someone use a different adjective, e.g. I have never seen someone use "discretely converges" to say that something "converges in the discrete topology".

Answer (score 0):

"Weakly" is not always associated with a weak topology.  For example, there are [weakly prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_prime_number) with no weak topology in sight.

Comment: If an author talks about the weak topology, and he uses the term "weakly" in this context, it would be understood in one way, I believe.The question is, how do you explain to someone what you mean by "weakly",when you are working with the weak topology,instead of defining what "converges weakly,weakly open,weakly continuous,etc"mean in this context? It would take long time to define.Could you say in a short sentence:"we use the term "weakly" to something if it has this property with respect to the weak topology",or is there a better way?(So that I could do the same to other kind of topologies)

Comment: Context is important, as is standard usage.  But it never hurts to be as clear as possible, so don't be afraid to spill a few extra drops of ink to state a definition explicitly whenever there might be some doubt.